# How to do PHP array_intersect by keys not by values?

Tags: php, arrays, array-intersect

`$master = ['111' => 'foo', '124' => 'bar', '133' => 'baz'];`

`$check = ['111' => 14, '133' => 23 ]';`

I want to remove all keys from `$master` that do not exists in `$check`.
So the result in this example should be:

`$newMaster = ['111' => 'foo', '133' => 'baz'];`

Any idea how to do this ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: *array_intersect by keys* <- remove 3 characters (excluding spaces :) and add an underscore to it, and you have your answer: `array_intersect_key`

Comment: Partial dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11644267/3933332 (Just without the flipping of the second array)

Comment: @Rizier123 five characters to be painfully precise ;-)

Comment: @Havelock I excluded the spaces, so `by` and the `s` from keys = 3 ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, simply use [`array_intersect_key()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php)

```
$newMaster = array_intersect_key($master, $check);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you can simply use:

```
var_dump(array_intersect_key($master, $check));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$master = ['111' => 'foo', '124' => 'bar', '133' => 'baz'];

$check = ['111' => 14, '133' => 23 ];


$intersectArray = array_intersect_key($master, $check);
```

Here key will compare using `array_intersect_key()` function it will compare your $check key in $master and give you result where $check key is matched in $master and you got output `['111' => 'foo', '133' => 'baz'];`  in `$intersectArray`

For more details you will check this link http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php