# Get values from second array where keys match

Tags: php

I have two arrays, the following:

```
$arr1 = array("Key1"=>1, "Key2"=>2, "Key3"=>3);
```

My second array is the following:

```
$arr2 = array("Key2", "Key3");
```

What I would like to get is the values where Key2 and Key3 matches. I would also like those values to be returned as an array so I end up with the following:

```
array(2,3)
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11644267/3933332 + Take a look at `array_values()` to reindex the array with numerical keys

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11644267/array-intersect-on-key-in-array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use of 3 three array functions to achieve this.

```
$arr1 = array("Key1"=>1, "Key2"=>2, "Key3"=>3);
$arr2 = array("Key2", "Key3");

$arr3 = array_values(array_intersect_key($arr1, array_flip($arr2)));
print_r($arr3);
```

**The output:**

> Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 3 )

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr1 = array("Key1"=>1, "Key2"=>2, "Key3"=>3);
$arr2 = array("Key2", "Key3");

$result = array();

foreach($arr1 as $key => $value) {
    if(in_array($key, $arr2)) {
        array_push($result, $arr1[$key]);
    }
}

var_dump($result);
```

or as mentioned in the comments:

```
$arr1 = array("Key1"=>1, "Key2"=>2, "Key3"=>3);
$arr2 = array("Key2", "Key3");

$result = array_intersect_key($arr1, array_flip($arr2));

var_dump($result);
```